# What is the most valuable tree here?

Tags: trees, fruit-trees, nut-trees

I happen to live in what is now USDA climate zone 6a with a dry climate. I have some space around my house, and I'd like to plant some trees, but I can't figure out which trees would have the most economic value.  My end goal would be to grow 5ish trees of 3ish species from the top 20 of the list.

I understand that there are a lot of variables, but I was hoping to find a website with a database that would offer 5 to 10 suggestions based on my parameters. I suspect that it's dry enough that after irrigation, trees are a money loser, but I can't get much perspective without knowing the value of a grown (or producing) tree. I understand that the value of shade (unless it reduces your cooling bills or rooftop solar conversion), beauty and privacy are extras and tough to measure, and that I may move away before the "investment" matures, but are there either website or specific suggestions?

Comment: You need to clarify this question as everyone assigns a different value to the things trees provide:  do you value food  ( acorns, hazelnuts..) which you can have every year over growing a black walnut for thirty years and getting cash for the wood?

Comment: Unless "dry climate" is "full-on desert" suitable trees that don't require irrigation are likely extant. Try "Tree Crops - A Permanent Agriculture" by J. Russell Smith (available as a free ebook several places on the web and un-free some other plaaces, but the free version is not an illicit one.)

Comment: As for "most valuable here" and then not giving a general location on the planet, - not helpful.

Comment: @kevinskio Economic means the monetary output. So, if you produce an average amount of crop at dollars per amount over time years, that's amount(in dollars)*time plus whatever the wood is worth at the end of the tree's life.

Comment: If "some trees" means 5, what kind of mega-harvest do you expect? If it means 100s, wouldn't it make sense to hire a farmer who has experience where you don't?

Comment: @Ecnerwal Thank you for the book resource. I'm not providing any personally identifiable information to the internet. While I only want an answer to my specific location, I was hoping for an answer for locations in general - that would make this question more valuable to more people as most people live somewhere. I also wanted to make sure not to get a website with the most expensive woods in the world (where 'here' means Earth).

Comment: @YosefBaskin I expect that if I planted a fruit tree, I would have enough fruit that I was sick of it by the end of the harvest. Alas, I don't have space for hundreds of trees. In any event, I may hire somebody to help me get started no matter the humble size of my arboretum.

Comment: Nobody needs your street address, but things suitable for the general geographical area vary more than "zone6a" "dry climate" will tell.

Comment: @Ecnerwal You'd probably want soil type, how much room the tree would have, what kind of sun to expect... All things which would make this question and answer valuable for far fewer people - are you suggesting that I remove the climate information to make it more valuable to more people?

Comment: To me the question is naive. 5 trees is nothing for forest industry (where you may find some economic calculations). Your case is about finding a niche (so good luck finding data). So go to a specialized nursery (specialty) or bonsai: the money is many factors more than forest industry, and a lot shorter investment time.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi There are plenty of trees whose economic value is leading to extinction. If everybody planted 5 economically valuable trees in their yard, do you think their extinction would remain imminent? The perception of naïveté usually represents a failure of imagination.

Comment: Yes. Economic value has nothing to do with extinction, and on a yard doesn't solve the problem (you miss all ecosystem which it is necessary and all minor species). I'm an engineer and I do a lot of research with economists (university researchers). It is not lack of imagination: it is knowledge of economics applied where data is lacking (so to get data).

Comment: In any case: what is your metric about "value"? Profit, or for humanity? Which discount rate/interest do you apply (it is a can of worms in economics, but if you look short term profit, which seldom a tree is giving you). How much do you valuate all the co-benefits? (shadows, beauty of a tree, the smell, birds, etc.). How much are you risk adverse? (tree may get diseases or broke because weather), with 3 species 5 trees you cannot leverage the risk so you should valuate it. And all opportunity costs (you are investing on long term and unknown return: very volatile market).

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I'm looking asking only about the potential revenue side of the equation here. I believe there is enough easily-located information about specific tree species that I can make decisions about the rest of the variables you list once I have a truncated list of trees to research. By the way, is it common to question first the sophistication and then the motives of people who ask questions here?

Comment: This is a reference site (not a forum), so there is some need to interpret questions to give generic answers (searchable, and useful for many people). On the other hand, the question cannot be too generic, or the answer may not be valid on most occasions. (Gardening SE may not be the best example on SE family). Your question (to me) is borderline to flags: *off-topic* or *need focus*, so the huge amount of comments.

Comment: This is a gardening question with a very focused answer.  The 'useful for many people' quality has been fought by the commenters in the form of 'give me more information about your particular situation'. The real reason for comments and poor answer is that this community doesn't know and can't find it and that's an uncomfortable thing for people who may believe in permaculture ideals. If such an ordering of information doesn't exist, that's an answer too, and I can make that work.

Answer (score 2):

If you aren't engaging in actual agriculture, a tree's 'economic value' doesn't make much sense to me.  Economic value is what the tree would be worth to other people, and who cares about them?  The most valuable tree is the one you appreciate being near most.

Well, not everyone thinks like me.  [Arbor Day](https://www.arborday.org/calculator/treeInfo.cfm) will let you put in your ZIP code and give you a list of suitable trees, and even produce a dollar value for the tree.  They assign dollar values to shade, CO2 sequestration, stormwater mitigation, air quality, all kinds of things they can put a number next too.

Personally, those numbers mean nothing to me.  The internet is full of better tree selection databases like [this one](https://selectree.calpoly.edu/) that let you input different tree parameters, and get a list of candidates back.

Is it a good tree for children to climb, or hang a swing from?  Does it aggravate someone's allergies?  When does it flower?  Does it have a smell?  How does it look in the autumn?  And the winter?  Does it drop leaves?  How many leaves, and all at once or do they drizzle off?  Is it culturally important? How does it fit into the local ecosystem?  Does it give me bragging rights over my neighbor? Will it grow to a size the location is suited for? Is it beautiful, strong and noble?

You can't answer those questions with a number.

Comment: Ooh, a frame challenge. Economic value would be total value of the annual crop I don't have to buy (retail price for crop consumed) plus the value of the wood at the end minus the cost of production. It's a number that an actual arboriculturist would need (though, obviously at wholesale and for the whole crop) and I was hoping there was a resource for that. While I agree that that one number won't tell me everything, it will give me a place to start. The websites you've provided do not contain any information that I asked for.

Comment: @user121330 I can almost guarantee you, the global economy will produce any harvest more reliably and economically than we can with our hobby orchards / tree farms.  You are kind of dancing around if you expect edible harvests or lumber or both, without even sharing what kind or size of lot this imaginary tree farm will be on.  The question is nearly "what is the formula for agribusiness management?"

Comment: @user121330 What are you looking for that the Arbor Day site does not provide?  If you are talking agriculture numbers, to give you a sense of why I think it's a dead end - my old neighbor had a large, healthy white oak taken down.  He paid a tree service $2,300 to remove the tree, and received $1,500 for the lumber from a local mill.  Another neighbor kept a stand of apple trees, and spent many hours every year caring for them.  He got maybe 60lbs of fruit per season, which sells for maybe $140 here.  All of those trees were excellent investments.

Comment: The Arbor Day site provides information on a given tree. Which I would delve into happily if I knew which tree to ask about - which it doesn't provide. As for the calculations you've provided ... if I hire out tree removal, one might suppose that mitigating its costs would be better than paying for them in full. Sometimes it's best to say 'I don't know if such a resource exists.'

Comment: So something like "Oak trees yield $850 in lumber after 7 years growth, apple trees yield $85 / year in fruit"?

Comment: I could work with that - there's a market for fruit woods, but I can do addition.

Comment: The point I'm getting at is that a list like that does not and can not exist without being uselessly facile. What water resources are available to you? What are the plethora of critical soil parameters? Weed pressure? What is the cost of labor, skilled and unskilled? What do the relevant commodity markets look like, and how hard would hedging be? What equipment do you have available, and can you maintain it? If the same crop made 'sense' for everyone, every farm would grow it. I admire your goals as I understand them, but you will find better guidance in an agriculture science program.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149804/discussion-between-user121330-and-mackm).